# Implementing websockets with angular, node and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, websocket

I have a Angular app that serves content from a Node.js API which gets the data from a MySQL database. The node API server just gets the data from the database, it doesn't insert anything. A Spring Boot API microservice inserts data into the database.

How would I implement WebSockets so every time the Spring Boot API inserts something into the database, the content is served into the Angular app in real time.

I have a hard time finding tutorials on this topic, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your app will work in following model. i.e :

1. when page refreshed or loaded, base content will be retrieved from node API
2. web socket and watcher will based on Angular (client side) + spring boot (server side). web socket implementation doesn't rely on node API.
3. You need to create client sender and receiver with Angular
4. Spring boot receiver and sender for mysql, Also to inform client.
5. When there is new text entered, client and server will communicate via web socket. You don't need to return any data in spring boot but spring boot web socket should inform the client about the new connection/text etc.

Please check below link. Which demonstrates socket implementation of Angular + Spring boot.

Link :

1. [Spring Boot Angular Websocket](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-websocket)
2. [Angular 6 WebSocket example with Spring Boot WebSocket Server | SockJS + STOMP](https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-6/angular-6-websocket-example-with-spring-boot-websocket-server-sockjs-stomp)

Comment: Please share some code snippet on what have you tried so far.